# iOS save to Photos not working

Tags: avfoundation, ios11, swift4.1

I am developing my app using Swift 4 and iOS 11.

The problem is I can have the UIImage shown in the UIImageView, but I cannot save it into my iPhone's Photo Album. I have been searching for a long time but don't know how to solve it.

Here is part of my code:

Put all the videoCapture code in `VideoCapture.swift`.

```
public class VideoCapture: NSObject, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
public var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
public var fps = 15

let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "net.machine.cameraqueue")
var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?
var image: UIImage?

public func setUp(sessionPreset: AVCaptureSession.Preset = .medium, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    queue.async {
        let success = self.setUpCamera(sessionPreset: sessionPreset)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(success)
        }
    }
}

public func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    image = sampleBuffer.image()
}

func setUpCamera(sessionPreset: AVCaptureSession.Preset) -> Bool {
    captureSession.beginConfiguration() // begin configuration (not commited yet)
    captureSession.sessionPreset = sessionPreset

    guard let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video) else {    //set to video mode
        print("Error: No video devices available")
        return false
    }
    guard let videoInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) else {      //set device input
        print("Error: could not create AVCaptureDeviceInput")
        return false
    }

    if captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput) { // add device input
        captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
    }

    // previewLayer setup
    let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
    previewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
    self.previewLayer = previewLayer

    // video output setup
    let settings: [String: Any] = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA),]
    videoOutput.videoSettings = settings
    videoOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
    videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)
    if captureSession.canAddOutput(videoOutput) {
        captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
    }

    videoOutput.connection(with: AVMediaType.video)?.videoOrientation = .portrait
    captureSession.commitConfiguration()
    return true
}

public func toggleRunning() {
    if captureSession.isRunning {
        captureSession.stopRunning()
    } else {
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }
}
}

extension CMSampleBuffer {
func image(orientation: UIImageOrientation = .up, scale: CGFloat = 1.0) -> UIImage? {
    if let buffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(self) {
        let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: buffer)
        return UIImage(ciImage: ciImage, scale: scale, orientation: orientation)
    }
    return nil
}
}
```

`ViewController.swift` file is as:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var videoPreview: UIView!

    var videoCapture: VideoCapture!
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 2)
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setUpCamera()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showPhotoSegue" {
            let previewVC = segue.destination as! PreviewViewController
            previewVC.image = videoCapture.image
        }
    }

    @IBAction func toggleCamera(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPhotoSegue", sender: nil)
    }

    func setUpCamera() {
        videoCapture = VideoCapture()
        videoCapture.fps = 50
        videoCapture.setUp(sessionPreset: AVCaptureSession.Preset.vga640x480) { success in
            if success {
                if let previewLayer = self.videoCapture.previewLayer {
                    self.videoPreview.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
                    self.resizePreviewLayer()
                }
                self.videoCapture.toggleRunning()
            }
        }
    }

    func resizePreviewLayer() {
        videoCapture.previewLayer?.frame = videoPreview.bounds
    }
    }
    }
```

`PreviewViewController.swift` is as follow:

```
class PreviewViewController: UIViewController {

var image: UIImage?
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageView.image = self.image
}

@IBAction func cancelButton(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
    print(type(of: self.imageView.image!))
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.imageView.image!, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
}

@objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if let error = error {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac,animated: true)
    } else {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your altered image has been saved!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac,animated: true)
    }
}
}
```

I used a segue to go from ViewController to PreviewViewController, and passed the image in ViewController to the imageView in PreviewViewController. But why doesn't it store the image in the Photo Album?

By the way, I have added all the privacy authorization in `info.plist`.

Comment: Where is saveButton called?

Comment: The saveButton is called in the new view, If the user click on the "save" button.

Comment: Have you displayed the dialog asking for access to the photolibrary?

Comment: Yes, they are all in the info.plist.

Comment: Does a dialog display before you try to save your image?

Answer (score 2):

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum() is a pretty old api I believe. You probably want to use the Photos framework to save images. The following code will request access to the photolibrary and then save your image.

```
func saveImage(image : UIImage) {
    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9)
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { [unowned self] status in
        if status == .authorized {
            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                let creationRequest = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()
                creationRequest.addResource(with: .photo, data: data, options: nil)
            }, completionHandler: { success, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error occured while saving photo to photo library: \(error)")
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you have this as the top of your file

```
import Photos
```